# Why is the upload button shown so slowly?

Tags: php, jquery, html, file-upload, uploadify

I am working on an existing project. I use the jQuery Uploadify plugin to upload files. The following button code is used to upload files:

```
<div>
     <input width="167" type="file" height="47" name="file_upload" class="file_upload" id="file_upload" style="display: none;">
     <object width="167" height="47" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/uploadify/uploadify.swf" id="file_uploadUploader" style="visibility: visible;"><param name="quality" value="high">
         <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
         <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain">
         <param name="flashvars" value="uploadifyID=file_upload&amp;pagepath=/en/media-maker/&amp;script=/en/media-maker/upload/file&amp;folder=&amp;scriptData=level%3D1%26folderid%3D15%26symfony%3Dbtt461h1nor36k2taotp6jhku4&amp;width=167&amp;height=47&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;method=POST&amp;queueSizeLimit=20&amp;simUploadLimit=1&amp;hideButton=true&amp;fileDesc=Image / Video / Audio&amp;fileExt=*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png;*.bmp;*.svg;*.avi;*.divx;*.dvx;*.dv;*.asf;*.asx;*.3gp;*.3g2;*.3ivx;*.3vx;*.mov;*.mp4;*.m4v;*.mpg;*.mpeg;*.qt;*.rm;*.swf;*.wmv;*.mkv;*.mts;*.part;*.mp3;&amp;multi=true&amp;auto=true&amp;sizeLimit=524288000&amp;fileDataName=Filedata&amp;queueID=uploadList">
     </object>
</div>
```

My problem is that this button appears very late when I refresh the webpage. This button appears only after the whole page is uploaded. Sometimes this button does not appear on some browsers and slow internet connection. How do I make it appear faster?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `<object>` is your button and it's some sort of .swf flash file ... well the browser can't display it until it downloads the whole thing from `/uploadify/uploadify.swf` ... Not to mention it has to fire up the flash plugin just to render a simple button. This is why it's slow.

I can't say I would ever advocate using a flash file for a button when CSS has is now so well-supported by so many browsers. I might go so far as to call it completely nonsensical.

Answer (score 3):

First of all why are you using flash for this? Kill the flash and do a pure jQuery-PHP AJAX implementation and use an image to make the button look pretty. Flash really should be limited to video players only and even that will soon no longer be the case with HTML5.

I just looked up uploadify and you should definitely pick a different tool Avoid using flash at all costs. I have been doing web development professionally for 5 years now and 10 if you include when I first started playing with it as a hobby. I can tell you from personal experience that when it comes to flash just say no.

Below I have included a list of alternatives that I found in a different StackOverflow answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072889/uploadify-alternative-need-to-upload-large-1gb-files). From what I see I think that "Plupload" and "jQuery AJAX File Upload" look good.

- [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/)
- [Valums AJAX Uploader](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)
- [AJAX Multiple File Upload Form using jQuery](http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/ajax-multiple-file-upload-form-using-jquery/)
- [jQuery AJAX File Upload](http://cool-javascripts.com/jquery/jquery-ajax-file-upload.html)
- [jQuery Multiple File Upload Plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/#)
- [Digitalarld Swiff AJAX Uploader](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/3-0/showcase/photoqueue/)
- [jQUploader](http://pixeline.be/experiments/jqUploader/test.php)
- [AJAX File Upload](http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/)

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that flash and js are both the last things that most browsers load. If you put an image in place for the button and just assign the appropriate JS to it then it will look and work just fine.

Comment: `$flash = function($myPage) { return "flash + $mypage == awful"; }`

Comment: The reason for using flash is to provide certain client side functionality such as max file-size validation, file type checks, progress/speed status etc. That flash is evil is not news. There just weren't many alternatives in 2008.

Comment: Flash is not a reason for those things. You can do all those things with JavaScript and PHP. For the progress you usually still need a server side plugin that can report back the progress. There is a simple php PECL plugin for this that JavaScript can interact with as well. While flash isn't evil (I never said that) it is a resource hog, a security hole that has to be plugged on both ends, and isn't supported in the mobile world anyway.